# About Peskin-Schroeder Eqs.(3.16)-(3.17)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, angular-momentum, metric-tensor, lie-algebra

This is a page of the Peskin-Schroeder QFT textbook,

[image]

I am quite baffled by equation 3.16.

Why is it a natural generalization of the former Euclidean 3d case? How to derive 3.17 from 3.16? The problem is, how to interpreter $\partial^\mu$? Is it different from $\partial_\mu$? Namely, is it that $$(\partial^0, \partial^1, \partial^2, \partial^3 ) = (\partial_0, -\partial_1, -\partial_2, -\partial_3)~?$$

If I were to plug the formula 3.16 into 3.17 and do the calculation mechanically, I would have $\partial^\nu x^\rho$. What is it?

For a newbie like me, the biggest barrier is the upper and lower indices.

Comment: Check out Zee's group theory book pg. 441 for explanation of the Lorentz algebra (eq. 3.16 & 3.17).  I recommend learning group theory before reading QFT.

Comment: Why there's i in the final expression. [J,J] has two i inside and put two i out becomes -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the calculation is straightforward (and a good exercise) I just summarize the main points:

Use the metric $g^{\mu\nu}$ to 'change' between **co-** (lower) and **contravariant** (upper indices) components, for more details see **dual spaces**. This already answer one question: Both are related via

$\partial^\mu = g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\nu$ (sum over $\nu$ is assumed - see Einstein convention).

or the other way around

$\partial_\mu = g_{\mu\nu}\partial^\nu$. (Note $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the inverse of $g^{\mu\nu}$, here (flat spacetime) it is the same matrix. Yes, in general, they are different because they are *dual* to each other.)

The only 'tricky' point in the calculation is the *proper contraction* of terms like $\partial^\nu x^\rho$:

Since $\partial^\nu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\nu}$ we have to use the metric once to perform the derivative in the "same space":

Only $\partial_\nu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}$ can act on $x^\rho$ **not** $\partial^\nu$ (both $x$-indices are at the same position) with the result $\partial_\nu x^\rho = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x^\nu} = \delta_\nu^\rho$ (= Kronecker Symbol: only = 1 if $\nu = \rho$ otherwise = 0).

In total: $\partial^\nu x^\rho = g^{\nu\mu}\partial_\mu x^\rho = g^{\nu\mu}\delta_\mu^\rho= g^{\nu\rho}$.

Two last comments: keep in mind that the metric is symmetric, hence $g^{\mu\nu}=g^{\nu\mu}$, and remember that two partial derivatives always commute, i.e., $\partial_\nu \partial_\mu = \partial_\mu \partial_\nu$.